# Parsing XML with Python Error: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The logic here is: If the page-element does not contain "| kasteeltype" then remove page-element, otherwise keep the page-element.

```
#Import ElementTree
import defusedxml.ElementTree as ET

#Set Tree & Root
tree = ET.parse("nlwiki-20221020-pages-meta-current1.xml-p1p134538")
root = tree.getroot()

#Namespaces
NSPage = "{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}page"
NSRevision = "{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}revision"
NSText = "{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}text"

#Modify XML
for page in root.findall(NSPage):
  for revision in page.findall(NSRevision):
    text = revision.find(NSText)
    kasteeltype = "| kasteeltype"
    if kasteeltype not in text.text:
      root.remove(page)

#Output
tree.write("output.xml")
```

This code results in the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [8], line 18
     16 text = revision.find(NSText)
     17 kasteeltype = "| kasteeltype"
---> 18 if kasteeltype not in text.text:
     19   root.remove(page)
     20 else:

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I'm a bit clueless now about how to proceed.

The XML-file can be found here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/nlwiki/20221020/nlwiki-20221020-pages-meta-current1.xml-p1p134538.bz2

It is quite a large file since it is a wikipedia dump.

The expected result should be that all page elements that do not contain  the string "|  kasteeltype" in the text element under the parent revision should be removed.

Comment: Your sample code runs without a problem for me, so can't comment on what your problem is (except that Snyk considers xml.etree.ElementTree insecure and recommends defusedxml.ElementTree as a replacement)

Comment: My apologies, the code does indeed work on this file, however, it does not run on the bigger file I edit my post and include the link.

I changed my code to defusedxml.ElementTree.

Comment: There are lines a'la `<text bytes="0" />` which have no text.text property. Check if text.text is None before trying to access it with 'not in text.text'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the element was found

```
 pages = root.findall(NSPage)
 if pages is not None:
    for page in pages: 
      revisions = page.findall(NSRevision)
      if revisions is not None:
        for revision in revisions:
          text = revision.find(NSText)
          if text is not None and text.text is not None:
             kasteeltype = "| kasteeltype"
             if kasteeltype not in text.text:
               root.remove(page)
```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately got the same error.

Comment: `if text.text is not None:`

Comment: more verifications added. try it.